# how to add multiple items in the model in the mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, model

i have 2 devices , each device having 10 lattitude and 10 longitude values. im having 2 devices which has 10 lat long values of each , but only 10 items are adding another 10 items of device 2 data are getting replaced in the model. how to add 2 devices data in the model like this without creating 2 different classes for each.

im accessing the model values in the view like this

```
 @Model[0].latitude.ToString()....@Model[9].latitude.ToString(), 
 @Model[1].longitude.ToString()....@Model[9].latitude.ToString(),
```

i should be able to access the 2 different devices data in the view like this

```
@Model[0][0]...[0][9];
@Model[1][0]...[1][9];
```

code

```
  public ActionResult Index()
     {
      List<AssetTrackerViewModel> model = new List<AssetTrackerViewModel>();
      model.AddRange(getAssetDetails("ED"));
      model.AddRange(getAssetDetails("EE"));
      return View(model);
     }
     private List<AssetTrackerViewModel> getAssetDetails(string deviceID)
       {
        List<AssetTrackerViewModel> model = new List<AssetTrackerViewModel>();

         try
          {
           WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(@"url");
           req.Method = "GET";
           req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + "a2VybmVsc3BoZXJlOmtlcm5lbHNwaGVyZQ==";
           HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
           var encoding = resp.CharacterSet == "" ? Encoding.UTF8 : Encoding.GetEncoding(resp.CharacterSet);
           using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
            {
             var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding);
             var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

             var Pirs = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AssetDetail>>(responseString);
             var items = Pirs.Where(a => !a.dataFrame.EndsWith("AAAAAAAAAAA="))
              .GroupBy(a => a.dataFrame.Substring(a.dataFrame.Length - 12))
              .Select(g => g.First())                                                                 .OrderByDescending(a => a.timestamp).Take(10);
              foreach (var item in items)
                {
                 byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(item.dataFrame.ToString());
                 string hex = BitConverter.ToString(data);//converting base 64 to hexcode
                 string formattedHex = BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace(@"-", string.Empty);
                 string longitude = formattedHex.Substring(14, formattedHex.Length - 14);//04AC07EB
                 long longitudeValue = Convert.ToInt64(longitude, 16);
                 string longvalue = longitudeValue.ToString();
                 longvalue = longvalue.Insert(2, ".");
                 string latitude = formattedHex.Substring(6, formattedHex.Length - 14); //010A366B
                 long lat = Convert.ToInt64(latitude, 16);
                 string latvalue = lat.ToString();
                 latvalue = latvalue.Insert(2, ".");
                 AssetTrackerViewModel assetModel = new AssetTrackerViewModel();
                 assetModel.deviceid = deviceID;
                 assetModel.latitude = latvalue;
                 assetModel.longitude = longvalue; 
                 model.Add(assetModel);
                 }
                }
              }   
               return model;
            }

    view model

          public class AssetDetail
            {
             public long id { get; set; }
             public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
             public string dataFrame { get; set; }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify you classes:

```
// this is class that represents single device
public class AssetTracker
{
   public AssetTracker()
   {
      latitude = new List<string>();
      longitude = new List<string>();
   }

   public string deviceid {get; set;}
   public List<string> latitude {get; set;}
   public List<string> longitude {get; set;}
}
```

Then you viewmodel:

```
public class AssetTrackersViewModel
{
   public AssetTrackersViewModel()
   {
     AssetTrackers = new List<AssetTracker>();
   }

   public List<AssetTracker> AssetTrackers {get;set}
}
```

Then your `getAssetDetails` method:

```
private AssetTracker getAssetDetails(string deviceID)
{
  var assetTracker = new AssetTracker { deviceid = deviceID };

 try
  {
   WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(@"url");
   req.Method = "GET";
   req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + "a2VybmVsc3BoZXJlOmtlcm5lbHNwaGVyZQ==";
   HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
   var encoding = resp.CharacterSet == "" ? Encoding.UTF8 : Encoding.GetEncoding(resp.CharacterSet);
   using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
    {
     var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding);
     var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

     var Pirs = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AssetDetail>>(responseString);
     var items = Pirs.Where(a => !a.dataFrame.EndsWith("AAAAAAAAAAA="))
      .GroupBy(a => a.dataFrame.Substring(a.dataFrame.Length - 12))
      .Select(g => g.First())                                                                 .OrderByDescending(a => a.timestamp).Take(10);
      foreach (var item in items)
        {
         byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(item.dataFrame.ToString());
         string hex = BitConverter.ToString(data);//converting base 64 to hexcode
         string formattedHex = BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace(@"-", string.Empty);
         string longitude = formattedHex.Substring(14, formattedHex.Length - 14);//04AC07EB
         long longitudeValue = Convert.ToInt64(longitude, 16);
         string longvalue = longitudeValue.ToString();
         longvalue = longvalue.Insert(2, ".");
         string latitude = formattedHex.Substring(6, formattedHex.Length - 14); //010A366B
         long lat = Convert.ToInt64(latitude, 16);
         string latvalue = lat.ToString();
         latvalue = latvalue.Insert(2, ".");

         assetTracker.latitude.Add(latvalue);
         assetTracker.longitude.Add(longvalue);
         }

         return assetTracker;
        }
      }   
    }
```

Then:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
  var model = new AssetTrackersViewModel();
  model.AssetTrackers.Add(getAssetDetails("ED"));
  model.AssetTrackers.Add(getAssetDetails("EE"));
  return View(model);
 }
```

Then, you can call in Razor:

`@model AssetTrackersViewModel`

for first 'device'

```
 @Model.AssetTrackers[0].latitude[0]
 @Model.AssetTrackers[0].longitude[0]

 @Model.AssetTrackers[0].latitude[9]
 @Model.AssetTrackers[0].longitude[9]
```

for second 'device'

```
 @Model.AssetTrackers[1].latitude[0]
 @Model.AssetTrackers[1].longitude[0]

 @Model.AssetTrackers[1].latitude[9]
 @Model.AssetTrackers[1].longitude[9]
```

Comment: Getting some errors due to names of view model and return types are not correct. can you check once.somewhere AssetTrackersViewModel and some where AssetTrackerViewModel

Comment: sorry wrote that it notepad :) Where exactly you got the error?

Comment: your razor view must have `@model AssetTrackersViewModel` declared on top

Comment: i already declared it like this"
@model smartpond.Models.AssetTrackersViewModel". error -Non-invocable member 'AssetTrackersViewModel' cannot be used like a method. line - var model = AssetTrackersViewModel();

Comment: no, why you use list - `@model smartpond.Models.AssetTrackersViewModel` that is your model type

Comment: Ok, `new` keyword was missing: should be that: `var model = new AssetTrackersViewModel();`

Comment: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'IEnumerable<AssetTracker>'  in this line- @: var myLatLng = {  lat: @Model.AssetTrackers[0].latitude[0]};]

Comment: change in AssetTrackersViewModel class : `public List<AssetTracker> AssetTrackers {get;set}` instead of `IEnumerable<AssetTracker> AssetTrackers {get;set}`

Comment: The type or namespace name 'AssetDetail' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference). line    var Pirs = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AssetDetail>>(responseString);

Comment: You removed your AssetDetail class definiton :) Restore it, as it was in your code.

Comment: now everything is working , but small error still have - device id is not getting in the model.in the view im getting (in console ) var myLatLng = { lat: 17.446266,lng: 78.382960,deviceId: E};error- uncaught referenceError E is not defined

Comment: @: var myLatLng = { lat: @Model.AssetTrackers[0].latitude[0],lng: @Model.AssetTrackers[0].longitude[0],deviceId: @Model.AssetTrackers[0].deviceid[0]};

Comment: `deviceid` is not an array - it is just a string field, so call it as:
`@Model.AssetTrackers[0].deviceid`.
`latitude` and `longitude` are arrays, `deviceid` is not